# I am using UISlider to as a seek bar in music player for iphone,but the song won't seek when I drag slider to fastfoward song

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
-(void)updateElapsedTime
{
   if (_audioPlayer)
   {
      if ([_audioPlayer isPlaying]==YES)
      {
          _ProgressSeekSlider.value=[_audioPlayer currentTime] / [_audioPlayer duration];//UISLider
      }

      [_StartTimeLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self formatTime:[_audioPlayer currentTime]]]];//Start Time Label which shows Time elapsed of song

      [_EndTimeLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self formatTime:[_audioPlayer duration]]]];//Label which shows the total song duration
   }
   [self updatePlayPauseImage];
   [self updateSongName];
   [self updateSeekBar];
}
```

When I drag the ProgreeSeekSlider to foward a song,it will go back to time elapsed but won't seek the song.
I want this slider to seek the song as well

Comment: You didn't show any code that actually changes the current position of the player.

Comment: Give me a code or method so that I can seek my song to any time when I drag seekbar (UISlider)

Comment: Sorry, SO doesn't work this way. You show us the code, we give you directions to fix it. Anyway, noone knows what type is your `_audioPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.Give me your email id,I will mail you the code.It is AVAudioPlayer

Comment: You can upload it to any file storage (or better to github) and post the link here.